# How can I create an AWS API Gateway custom domain to a domain which is already used in a CloudFront distibution with any downtime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to switch my site, which is currently CloudFront and Elastic Beanstalk, to API Gateway.

When I try to create the Custom Domain in API Gateway I get a message that there is already a CloudFront distribution for that domain, which is true. But if I remove that distribution my site will be down until the new distribution (for the API Gateway) will be up.

Is there anyway I can swap these or something ?

I do have control over the DNS records.

Comment: I'm assuming, you are using CloudFront for static assets only, in your Beanstalk based implementation?

Comment: There is no zero-downtime solution, because of the global namespace of CloudFront, which is also used by API Gateway, so @jenswalter has the only direct solution -- add the API Gateway endpoint's default name as an origin on your existing CloudFront distribution.  However... there's a workaround to minimize downtime, if you are using a subdomain (foo.example.com) rather than a naked domain (example.com).  Are you?

Comment: @YeshodhanKulkarni - no - I'm using CloudFront as a cache layer for the entire site - static & dynamic.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - It is the root domain (www)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked in the end :

1. Change the DNS to point directly at Elastic Beanstalk
2. Disable & Delete the original CloudFront distribution
3. Create a 'Custom Domain' in APIG (this also creates a CloudFront dist.)
4. Change the DNS to point at the new CloudFront dist. (you get the URL in the APIG console under Custom Domains)

Each of these steps takes a little time ... but there is no downtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can register your API-Gateway as cloudfront origin and then assign a separate behavior for you API calls.

If you need a step-by-step guide, you can use the following link:

[Processing A Contact Form Using AWS Cloudfront, API Gateway, Lambda and SES](https://www.codeengine.com/articles/process-form-aws-api-gateway-lambda/)

For a cloudformation setup you can use this description:

[hosting a Cloudfront site with S3 and API Gateway](https://apimeister.com/2017/05/09/hosting-a-cloudfront-site-with-s3-and-api-gateway.html)

Comment: I tried but this didn't work because API Gateway will return a 'Forbidden' if you try to access it from a domain which isn't registered with it as a Custom Domain. You can see this as an example - d2dce1w778hsrx.cloudfront.net. Thanks

Comment: The forbidden error is not generated by the missing Custom Domain (since those aren't necesary). I would guess that your Origin or Behavior is not correctly set up. Did you explicity whitelist the header fields? Path pattern matching is often a cause of error too. The origin has the stage as part of the path, But the Behavior already contains the first resource element of your API. Sadly there is no tooling on the AWS side to debug such a configuration, it is just trail an error.

Comment: In this case, whitelisting the `Host:` header would be expected to cause this error.

Comment: I tried a couple of configurations but I couldn't get it to work. And yes - APIG Is a pain for these things and many times the 'Forbidden' error is hiding something completely different. Thanks for the help anyway.